# Vuejs. How from string (props) make a function?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want from json in props transfer functions which been run from onclick. I can transfer function just as string and I read what method eval() can convert string to func, but I can't do this and this method is unsafe.

Here my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-trans-function-in-json-g74dl

Comment: What errors occur? Could you further describe what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should turn your function in real function and not 'text function'. Like so, you can always display function as text, and you don't need unsafe eval().

I forked your code : https://codesandbox.io/s/how-trans-function-in-json-f8f64